# D3: Example for hierarchical Matrix example

Tags: jquery, matrix, d3.js

I'm looking for an example graph in D3 that merges the idea of a hierarchical tree with a Matrix.

The idea would be that the x and y-axis are tree-like collapsable (e.g. something like: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025 or http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/partition.html or http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083 or maybe very simple like example 4 http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/ ) and then arrange them in a matrix form. (like: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/).

I browsed the examples online but couldn't find something that I can use as a starter.

Comment: Then use the D3.js library and create one. Go through the [tutorials](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials) and create something.Also check this [example](http://www.findtheconversation.com/concept-map/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circular packing is a d3 app using 2d matrix. Or create a treemap like d3 app yourself. You can search for a jquery treemap plugin.